# For Loop for Triangle c prog

Tags: c

I am creating a for loop function to draw a triangle. The idea is to input an odd number value which will be the Base.

It should turn out like that

```
`   +
   +++
  +++++
 +++++++ `
```

currently, my code runs to this part:

```
void draw(int a)
{
int i, j, row;
for (i=1; i<=a/2; i++) {
    printf(" ");
}
printf("*\n");
for (row=0; row<(a/2)-1; j++) {
    for (int k=1; k<=3; <#increment#>) {
        <#statements#>
    }
}
```

and I am stuck like should I start with for loop for space or + sign first?

Comment: I'm not sure what ´  + +++ +++++ +++++++´ means. What does this output have to do with a triangle? Can you be more specific? Also, please note that C and C++ are two different programming languages. Please decide which one you want to use and only tag your question with one of them!

Comment: Okay, now I understand what you are trying to achieve! I would do the following: First, loop through all rows. Within this loop, loop over all columns. In the inner loop, use an if-else statement to either insert a space or a star, based on the row index and column index.

Comment: so i should have a 'for' loop for rows, followed by column?
i just cant see the part. Are you able to elaborate further?

Comment: If I understood the question with the C tag correctly ??? Why are all the answers in C++ ???

Answer (score 0):

you'd better first define a method to print spaces,then with nested loops we do the code. outer for saves odd values and inner for prints Stars !

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void space(int n)
{
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    cout<<" ";
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter Odd Number >> \n";
    cin>>n;
    int k = n-1;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i+=2)
    {
        space(k--);
        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
        cout<<"*";
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! for now i am not very familiar with Cout and Cin.. ahah but I will try.. appreciated!

Comment: As I mentioned earlier: Please decide if you want to use C or C++. Using cin and cout is C++ only.

Answer (score 0):

> I am creating a for loop function to draw a triangle. The idea is to
> input an odd number value which will be the Base.

It is unclear why you are saying about an odd number when you provided a picture of a triangle with the even number 4.

> and I am stuck like should I start with for loop for space or + sign
> first?

This your question does not make a sense. Look at the picture you provided yourself. What is unclear?

The function can be written the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

FILE * draw( unsigned int n, char c, FILE *fp )
{
    const unsigned int MAX_VALUE = ( UINT_MAX - 1 ) / 2;
    
    if ( MAX_VALUE < n ) n = MAX_VALUE;
    
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        fprintf( fp, "%*c", ( int )( n - i ), c );
        
        for ( unsigned int j = 1; j < 2 * i + 1; j++ )
        {
            fputc( c, fp );
        }
        
        fputc( '\n', fp );
    }
    
    return fp;
}

int main(void)
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        const char c = '+';
        
        printf( "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): " );
        
        unsigned int n = 0;
        
        if ( scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;

        putchar( '\n' );
        
        fputc( '\n', draw( n, c, stdout ) );
    }
        
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 10

         +
        +++
       +++++
      +++++++
     +++++++++
    +++++++++++
   +++++++++++++
  +++++++++++++++
 +++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++++

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 9

        +
       +++
      +++++
     +++++++
    +++++++++
   +++++++++++
  +++++++++++++
 +++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 8

       +
      +++
     +++++
    +++++++
   +++++++++
  +++++++++++
 +++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 7

      +
     +++
    +++++
   +++++++
  +++++++++
 +++++++++++
+++++++++++++

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 6

     +
    +++
   +++++
  +++++++
 +++++++++
+++++++++++

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 5

    +
   +++
  +++++
 +++++++
+++++++++

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 4

   +
  +++
 +++++
+++++++

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 3

  +
 +++
+++++

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 2

 +
+++

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 1

+

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I have decorated your task a little. :) Whatever value you enter for the variable v, there will always be an odd number of characters at the base of the triangle.You should start with the space characters.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int v=10;
int p,x,i;
char ch1= ' ', ch;
for(i=0;i<v;i++)
{
    for(x=0;x<(v-i);x++)
        printf("%c",ch1);
    for(ch='A';ch<('A'+i);ch++)
        printf("%c",ch);
    for(p=0,x=('A'+i+p);x>='A';x--,p++)
        printf("%c",x);
    printf("\n");
}
    return 0;
}
```